# How to create border around menu item in Blogger blog?

Tags: css, blogger, menuitem

I'm trying to customize my blogger blog. I want to add a white border around the "SUBSCRIBE" menu item to make it more noticeable.

I've been reading some articles and they tell me to identify first the id of the specific menu item but when I right-click on "SUBSCRIBE" I only see  but no ID...

Edit: here is the code in question:

```
<div class="widget PageList" data-version="1" id="PageList1">
    <div class="widget-content">
        <div class="menus">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="parent"><a href="https://www.thekawaiifiles.com/">Home</a></li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="https://www.thekawaiifiles.com/p/about.html">About</a>
                <li class="parent"><a href="https://www.thekawaiifiles.com/p/archive.html">Archive</a></li>
                <li class="parent"><a href="https://urlshortenerlinkchangedforstackoverflow.com">Subscribe</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add your code, please.

Comment: Can you add snippet please?

Comment: Hi @jasie and Mordecai, sorry I couldn't give the code/snippet, I wasn't sure what you meant b/c I'm not familiar with this stuff. But thanks for trying to help! It's solved now thanks to [at] markmoxx ^^

Comment: @Mordecai sorry I couldn't give the code/snippet, I wasn't sure what you meant b/c I'm not familiar with this stuff. But thanks for trying to help! It's solved now thanks to [at] markmoxx ^^

Comment: SO doesn't work this way. You don't simply get your fix and then edit your question to say solved. the question is now useless, we don't see the issue and we don't see how the accepted answer solve it

Comment: Hi @TemaniAfif sorry about that, I didn't know. I only removed the link to my site and changed nothing else about the question. Next time I'll include links to screenshots or a test blog instead

Comment: Your question is still useless, we need the code in the question, not a link or a screenshot. The issue should be here not outside.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hmm... really sorry, [at] Mordecai and [at] jasie asked this too but I'm not sure which code to include. I'm not really familiar with html or css.. Can you point it out for me so I can add the code to the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your menu item has no ID, but you can target the last element in the menu by using

```
#PageList1 .nav li:last-child a {
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    padding: 4px;
}
```

If it's not always the last element in the menu, then you can target it using the `nth-child()` selector, i.e.

```
#PageList1 .nav li:nth-child(4) a {
    ...
}
```

Comment: omggg! Thanks so much @markmoxx it worked! And thanks for adding the info about the nth-child() selector too. It IS not the last element b/c the theme defaults categories as the last one so that was really helpful. ^_^

Comment: thanks so much for editing + adding the code!!